# C# WPF - Rectangle MouseEnter & MouseLeave events not working properly

Tags: c#, wpf, events

I add a bunch of rectangles to my WPF Canvas like this:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle
{
    Width = tuple.Width,
    Height = tuple.Height,
    Stroke = Brushes.Black,
    StrokeThickness = 1
};

rectangle.MouseEnter += (s, e) => rectangle.Stroke = Brushes.Gray;
rectangle.MouseLeave += (s, e) => rectangle.Stroke = Brushes.Black;

Canvas.SetLeft(rectangle, tuple.X);
Canvas.SetTop(rectangle, tuple.Y);
canvas.Children.Add(rectangle);
```

What did I expect:

- Border-Color of the rectangle the mouse is entering changes to gray and it stays gray as long as the mouse is inside of the area of that rectangle

What actually happens:

- The border color only changes to gray if the mouse is directly on the border but remains black if the mouse is anywhere else (even inside the rectangle).

So why is that? How can I implement my expected behaviour?

Comment: So the `MouseLeave` fires when in the body of the rectangle, that's strange and counter-intuitive

Comment: Can you reproduce this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

If you give the rectangle a fill, everything works as expected:

```
Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle
{
    Width = tuple.Width,
    Height = tuple.Height,
    Stroke = Brushes.DarkGray,
    StrokeThickness = 1,
    Fill = Brushes.Transparent
};
```